# regular expression to split

Tags: python, regex

I try to understand the regex in python. How can i split the following sentence with regular expression?

```
"familyname, Givenname A.15.10"
```

this is like the phonebook in python regex http://docs.python.org/library/re.html. The person maybe have 2 or more familynames and 2 or more givennames. After the familynames exist ', ' and after givennames exist ''. the last one is the office of the person. What i did until know is

```
 import re
 file=open('file.txt','r')
 data=file.readlines()
 for i in range(90):
person=re.split('[,\.]',data[i],maxsplit=2)
print(person)
```

it gives me a result like this

```
 ['Wegner', ' Sven Ake G', '15.10\n']
```

i want to have something like

```
 ['Wegner', ' Sven Ake', 'G', '15', '10']. any idea?
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: If you want to split, then split; don't use a regular expression.

Comment: i want to split the string exactly in ['familyname','givenname','office']. In the case that the person have more familynames or givennames this is not work. I want one element for many givennames or familynames. thanks

Comment: Again, if you know what your delimiter is,  you don't need a regex.  Split the string and be done with it.  Use the right tool for the right job.

Comment: in the case "Heubes, Daniel WP.04.02" this is working as i want but when the string is like "Heubes morales, Daniel mario WP.04.02" it brake

Comment: Ok sorry for my writting. I read the data from a file which contain different types for this reson i want regex. I did it with split() but didn't work

Comment: Could you post some of the data from your file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the regex world it's often easier to "match" rather than "split". When you're "matching" you tell the RE engine directly what kinds of substrings you're looking for, instead of concentrating on separating characters. The requirements in your question are a bit unclear, but let's assume that

- "surname" is everything before the first comma
- "name" is everything before the "office"
- "office" consists of non-space characters at the end of the string

This translates to regex language like this:

```
rr = r"""
    ^         # begin
    ([^,]+)   # match everything but a comma
    (.+?)     # match everything, until next match occurs
    (\S+)     # non-space characters
    $         # end
"""
```

Testing:

```
import re
rr = re.compile(rr, re.VERBOSE)
print rr.findall("de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan, Charles Ogier W.12.345")
# [("de Batz de Castelmore d'Artagnan", ', Charles Ogier ', 'W.12.345')]
```

Update:

```
rr = r"""
    ^         # begin
    ([^,]+)   # match everything but a comma
    [,\s]+    # a comma and spaces
    (.+?)     # match everything until the next match
    \s*       # spaces
    ([A-Z])   # an uppercase letter
    \.        # a dot
    (\d+)     # some digits
    \.        # a dot
    (\d+)     # some digits
    \s*       # maybe some spaces or newlines
    $         # end
"""

import re
rr = re.compile(rr, re.VERBOSE)
s = 'Wegner, Sven Ake G.15.10\n' 
print rr.findall(s)
# [('Wegner', 'Sven Ake', 'G', '15', '10')]
```

Comment: Thanks very nice answer. I want to split it because then i use some classes and i want to take this elements. Just for this reason

Comment: @ksofos: I'm not sure I understand... Could you expand your question and add an example of how you're using `split` on your inputs?

Comment: +1 for a clear explanation and respectful tone toward OP (and for not making fun of OPs language skills)

Comment: Very nice explanation but not for my specific problem. Thanks really nice i learned a lot from this

Comment: @ksofos: apart maybe from the `findall`, this fits your problem perfectly; you might want to look into how match objects work. +1 to the poster.

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is first split the family name by ,

`familyname, rest = text.split(',', 1)`

Then you want to split the office with the first space from the right.

`givenname, office = rest.rsplit(' ', 1)`

Comment: Yes thanks is working somehow but it take to the given name the first letter of the building. why?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. I thought that you meant that there was a . after given name. You'll need something a bit more complex then this, as this is incorrect. Apologizes.

Comment: I want to use your previous notation with regex but it gives me a result like this ['Wegner', ' Sven Ake G', '15.10\n'] i want to have something like ['Wegner', ' Sven Ake', 'G', '15', '10']. any idea?

Comment: Previous notation was re.split('[,\.]', text, maxsplit=2). The maxsplit is only allowing it to split it 2 times. As you want to split it more times, remove the maxsplit argument. Now you would get ['Wegner', ' Sven Ake G', '15', '10']. Then use the rsplit(' ', 1) on the second term to separate ' Sven Ake' from the 'G'.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that family names don't have a comma, you can take them easily. Given names are sensible to dots. For example:

```
Harney, PJ A.15.10
Harvey, P.J. A.15.10
```

This means that you should probably trim the rest of the record (family names are out) by a mask at the end (regex "maskpattern$").